# ERROR: Write access to member SASUSER.MYSALESDATA.DATA when using enterprise version of SAS

Tags: sas

I have two servers registered on SAS. When trying to create a SASUSER table in one server, it allows me and it gets created however on the other server when I try to create a sasuser table i get the following error:
ERROR: Write access to member SASUSER.Mytable

I am using SAS enterprise version and not the university edition.

How can I enable my write accesses on the other server?

Comment: Are you signing onto to both servers using the same username? Is your home directory the same on both servers, that is are both servers pointing to the same physical disk for your home directory?  If not does your home directory actually exist on both servers?

Comment: Does the second server session start with the `RSASUSER` option set?

Comment: Server side rights are controlled by the SAS host administrator - you will want to contact that team and have them check you login account rights.  Be sure to tell them which folder the troublesome SASUSER is (`%put %sysfunc(PATHNAME(SASUSER))`).  You also want to be sure the MySalesData Table is not open for editing in another process or EG session.

Comment: I eventually resolved the issue by using the export and exporting to a SAS table instead of using code to do that.